# PHP performance issue: pass referenced variable as non-ref parameter

Tags: php, performance, pass-by-reference

```
function M1($x, $y){}
function M2(&$x, $y){}
function M3(&$x, &$y){}

$arr = ['a' => ['b' => range(1, 1000)]];
$ref_arr = &$arr['a'];

$var = $ref_arr['b'];
$ref = &$ref_arr['b'];

//N->N, N->N
//0.003000020980835 sec.
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; ++$i)
    M1($var, $var);

//N->R, N->N   (slow)
//0.59903407096863 sec.
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; ++$i)
    M2($var, $var);

//N->R, N->R
//0.003000020980835 sec.
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; ++$i)
    M3($var, $var);

//R->N, R->N   (very slow)
//1.1980690956116 sec.
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; ++$i)
    M1($ref, $ref);

//R->R, R->N   (slow)
//0.58603405952454 sec.
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; ++$i)
    M2($ref, $ref);

//R->R, R->R
//0.003000020980835 sec.
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; ++$i)
    M3($ref, $ref);
```

As I know, when pass a reference variable as a non-reference parameter, PHP will copy the value. So this line takes the longest time.

> M1($ref, $ref); //1.1980690956116 sec.

But how to explain the performance of these 2 lines?

> M2($var, $var); //0.59903407096863 sec.
>
> M3($var, $var); //0.003000020980835 sec.

Comment: PHP uses copy-on-write. So passing a parameter doesn't need to make a copy. There's never any need to use references for performance. Use them only if the function needs to modify the caller's variable.

Comment: For "M2($var, $var)" I think the $var pass by ref is copied. so "M3($var, $var)" should copy $var twice, but it isnt happend in reality.

Comment: You can see the 3 functions doesn't modify any value. so for your conclusion, they should take the same time to run, but they are difference. @Barmar

Comment: Yeah, I guess what I was saying is true for ordinary variables. Apparently special treatment is needed for reference variables.

Comment: How many times did you run this to get an average for each function?

Comment: The comment is the total seconds, 10000 times, not for each. @NigelRen

Comment: I meant - did you run this script once or did you run it 10 times and average all the runs.  You have to take into account that other things on the system may affect each individual run and therefore it's isn't a fair assessment until you've tried it a few times.

Comment: @NigelRen yes serveral times.

Answer (score 1):

After serveral years since no one give me an answer, so I decide to answer by myself.

The reason is still the COPY-ON-WRITE mechanism in PHP, but when pass a parameter with different reference type, the copy happens immediately before the function call starts.

Define:

- N for non-ref variable
- R for ref variable
- -> for parameter passing

These 3 forms won't trigger parameter copy:

- N -> N
- R -> R
- N (ref count = 1) -> R

And for these 2 forms a parameter copy is always happens.

- R -> N
- N (ref count > 1) -> R

---

So when you decide to call a function with reference parameter (usually array functions like `sort`, `reset`), pass an array with refcount more than 1 is not a good idea.

Bad example:

```
$arr1 = [];
$arr2 = $arr1;
sort($arr1);
```

Good example:

```
$arr1 = [];
$arr2 = $arr1;
unset($arr2);
sort($arr1);
```